# Is there multiword synonyms with slop in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, synonym

ES allows a degree of flexibility into phrase matching by using the slop parameter:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html

We need this flexibility at index time, for multiword synonym matching, so

For example

```
flash light, LED light => LED
```

Would match

- Flash Utility Light
- Flash Utility Specialized Light

This might be a bad example though - in this case synonym flash to LED and search with slop, would solve this, but in my case I can't go back to query search, and it can only be phrase search.

Is there out of the box solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to expand your synonyms like that:

`flash light,LED light,LED=>flash light,LED light,LED`

While this will match your query, it will mess up highlight (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html )

Sadly there are no other solutions that I'm aware of at that point...